# How to Receive byte array from server in JavaScript and download as pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js

I am trying to to convert a byte array that is coming from the server and dowload as pdf, the download is working, but the file is coming corrupted.

I am trying doing that by JavaScript and i am using vue.js.

Function That Calls the server and brings the byte array:

```
function getManualAcademico(id) {
        const url = '/Sec/Ent/Get?d=';

        window.config.axios.get(url + id)
            .then(function (response) {
                var manualAcademico = response.data;

                Here i am calling the function sending the response data (array of bytes)
                DownloadPDF(manualAcademico);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                logInConsole(error);
            });
    }


    function DownloadPDF(manualAcademico) {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(manualAcademico.manual.$value);
        var a = window.document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
        a.download = "ManualAluno.pdf";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
```

And the server:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int Id)
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                manual = SEC.Get(Id)
            });
        }
```

The downloading is happening, but the file comes corrupted, any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` into request.

something likes:

```
window.config.axios.get({url: url + id, responseType: 'arraybuffer'})..
```

in this case